# Does the limit on the maximum number of SQL join tables apply to the whole query, or are subqueries counted separately?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have read about the [61 table join limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/joins-limits.html) in MySQL 5, but I'm not sure how it would apply to the folllowing:

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT * FROM tableA JOIN // Lots of other joins here...

    UNION

    SELECT * FROM tableB JOIN // Lots of other joins here...

    UNION

    SELECT * FROM tableC JOIN // Lots of other joins here...

    // etc...
)
```

Would I hit the limit with 61 tables in total across all the subqueries, or would it be 61 per UNIONed subquery?

Does this vary across DBs e.g. PostgreSQL, MSSQL, Oracle?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not keen on it myself, but the problem forces it on me (collecting unmarked student submissions of lots of different types and grouping them by course). I was previously keeping the UNION subqueries light and doing any filtering e.g. 'is the student in a class that the user actually teaches' in the outer part, but performance is poor and I need to get those things as direct JOINs meaning they need to be duplicated for each UNION subquery. It seems MySQL doesn't optimise subqueries very well :(

Comment: Yes the limit is different in differnt databases. However in any database if you are up against the limit, then you really need to reconsider your design. I don't know for sure about mysql but in SQl server those joins in the union would count towards the total

Comment: @HLGEM Thanks. I'd like to redesign the schema, but have no control over that as I'm making a plugin for a large open source project.

Comment: This is a good question.  Only way to find out is to test it though!

Comment: What if you built a temporary table and did inserts for each of your queries?  Might be faster.

Comment: @Jim This is a query that provides an AJAX response via a PHP script, so I think it would be slower as table would need to be rebuilt on every request.

Comment: I don't think there is any limit on the number of joins in Oracle and PostgreSQL. But I can't find the reference right now.

Comment: I'm not sure that the 61 limit of MySQL applies to Unioned tables, I think it affects Joins only. See: [SQL-Fiddle, union of 65 tables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25560/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be 61 per subquery. Here's a fiddle demonstrating this.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b219/5

I have a simple table with one row:

```
id    | value
1     | testvalue
```

The first query is just the table.

The second query joins the table with itself 61 times. It works fine.

The third query has a subquery containing 61 joins, which is itself joined with the table one more time. It works fine.

The fourth query joins the table 62 times. It fails.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it applies to whole query.  I have run into this.  In SQL 2005 the limit was 256.  We just upgraded to 2008 and I am not sure if there is a limit. Check out the official limits here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx  However, the best course of action is to either split the query into two or change the way that it is written.

Comment: As your link points, the number (of tables per SELECT statement) on 2008 and more recent versions is limited only by "available resources".