# Work around the 61 table JOIN limit in MySQL by nesting subqueries within each other

Tags: mysql, magento, join, left-join, entity-attribute-value

I figured out that you can get around the 61 table join limit in MySQL by using subqueries.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20134402/2843690

I'm trying to figure out how to *easily* use this in a program I'm working on to get a detailed product list from Magento (but I think the answer to this question could apply to a lot of situations where eav is involved). The tables that need to be joined look something like this:

```
catalog_product_entity
+-----------+----------------+
| entity_id | entity_type_id |
+-----------+----------------+
|         1 |              4 |
|         2 |              4 |
|         3 |              4 |
|         4 |              4 |
|         5 |              4 |
|         6 |              4 |
|         7 |              4 |
|         8 |              4 |
|         9 |              4 |
+-----------+----------------+

catalog_product_entity_int
+----------+----------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
| value_id | entity_type_id | attribute_id | entity_id | value |
+----------+----------------+--------------+-----------+-------+
|        1 |              4 |            2 |         1 |   245 |
|        2 |              4 |            3 |         1 |   250 |
|        3 |              4 |            4 |         1 |   254 |
|        4 |              4 |            2 |         2 |   245 |
|        5 |              4 |            3 |         2 |   249 |
|        6 |              4 |            4 |         2 |   253 |
|        7 |              4 |            2 |         3 |   247 |
|        8 |              4 |            3 |         3 |   250 |
|        9 |              4 |            4 |         3 |   254 |
+----------+----------------+--------------+-----------+-------+

eav_attribute
+--------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+
| attribute_id | entity_type_id | attribute_code | backend_type |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+
|            1 |              4 | name           | varchar      |
|            2 |              4 | brand          | int          |
|            3 |              4 | color          | int          |
|            4 |              4 | size           | int          |
|            5 |              4 | price          | decimal      |
|            6 |              4 | cost           | decimal      |
|            7 |              4 | created_at     | datetime     |
|            8 |              3 | name           | varchar      |
|            9 |              3 | description    | text         |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+

eav_attribute_option
+-----------+--------------+
| option_id | attribute_id |
+-----------+--------------+
|       245 |            2 |
|       246 |            2 |
|       247 |            2 |
|       248 |            3 |
|       249 |            3 |
|       250 |            3 |
|       251 |            4 |
|       252 |            4 |
|       253 |            4 |
|       254 |            4 |
+-----------+--------------+

eav_attribute_option_value
+----------+-----------+-------------------+
| value_id | option_id |       value       |
+----------+-----------+-------------------+
|       15 |       245 | Fruit of the Loom |
|       16 |       246 | Hanes             |
|       17 |       247 | Jockey            |
|       18 |       248 | White             |
|       19 |       249 | Black             |
|       20 |       250 | Gray              |
|       21 |       251 | Small             |
|       22 |       252 | Medium            |
|       23 |       253 | Large             |
|       24 |       254 | Extra Large       |
+----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

The program that I'm writing generated sql queries that looked something like this:

```
SELECT cpe.entity_id
, brand_int.value as brand_int, brand.value as brand
, color_int.value as color_int, color.value as color
, size_int.value as size_int, size.value as size

FROM catalog_product_entity as cpe

LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int as brand_int
ON (cpe.entity_id = brand_int.entity_id
AND brand_int.attribute_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option as brand_option
ON (brand_option.attribute_id = 2
AND brand_int.value = brand_option.option_id)
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value as brand
ON (brand_option.option_id = brand.option_id)

LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int as color_int
ON (cpe.entity_id = color_int.entity_id
AND color_int.attribute_id = 3)
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option as color_option
ON (color_option.attribute_id = 3
AND color_int.value = color_option.option_id)
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value as color
ON (color_option.option_id = color.option_id)

LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int as size_int
ON (cpe.entity_id = size_int.entity_id
AND size_int.attribute_id = 4)
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option as size_option
ON (size_option.attribute_id = 4
AND size_int.value = size_option.option_id)
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value as size
ON (size_option.option_id = size.option_id)
;
```

It was relatively easy to write the code to generate the query, and the query was fairly easy to understand; however, it's pretty easy to hit the 61 table join limit, which I did with my real-life data. I believe the math says 21 integer-type attributes would go over the limit, and that is before I even start adding varchar, text, and decimal attributes.

So the solution I came up with was to use subqueries to overcome the 61 table limit.

One way to do it is to group the joins in subqueries of 61 joins. And then all of the groups would be joined. I think I can figure out what the sql queries should look like, but it seems difficult to write the code to generate the queries. There is a further (albeit theoretical) problem in that one could again violate the 61 table limit if there were enough attributes. In other words, if I have 62 groups of 61 tables, there will be a MySQL error. Obviously, one could get around this by then grouping the groups of groups into 61. But that just makes the code even more difficult to write and understand.

I think the solution I want is to nest subqueries within subqueries such that each subquery  is using a single join of 2 tables (or one table and one subquery). Intuitively, it seems like the code would be easier to write for this kind of query. Unfortunately, thinking about what these queries should look like is making my brain hurt. That's why I need help.

What would such a MySQL query look like?

Comment: If your primary objective is to "get a detailed product list from Magento", why don't you include the the attributes you want to query in the flat table index, then just do a `select * from catalog_product_flat_1`?  Either that, or leverage the existing Magento models to create a collection, and select on the attributes you want to display.  Your SQL solution is an inefficient approach in my opinion.

Comment: @Axel catalog_product_flat requires a reindex to be current, I believe. Also catalog_product_flat doesn't have all of the information I want. As for magento collections, I am not very familiar with the inner workings of magento. And so far, I've found direct mysql queries to be significantly faster than using magento or the api's.

Comment: Also, I'm just curious. Even if it's not practical in this case, it could be useful for something later on. At the very least, I think it could be interesting.

Comment: I guess it depends what your goal is.  If you're building an extension, you should be leveraging the existing methods Magento provides in it's core Models.  I would recommend querying everything using Magento collections, then printing out the SQL Magento generates using: `$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');`.  This will show you the exact SQL used by Magento to gather all the various data and compile it into a single result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that joining too many attributes through an EAV design is likely to exceed the limit of joins. Even before that, there's probably a practical limit of joins because the cost of so many joins gets higher and higher geometrically. How bad this is depends on your server's capacity, but it's likely to be quite a bit lower than 61.

So querying an EAV data model to produce a result as if it were stored in a conventional relational model (one column per attribute) is problematic.

Solution: don't do it with a join per attribute, which means you can't expect to produce the result in a conventional row-per-entity format purely with SQL.

I'm not intimately familiar with the Magento schema, but I can infer from your query that something like this might work:

```
SELECT cpe.entity_id
, o.value AS option
, v.value AS option_value
FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS i 
  ON cpe.entity_id = i.entity_id AND i.attribute_id IN (2,3,4)
INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option AS o 
  ON i.value = o.option_id AND i.attribute_id = o.attribute_id
INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option_value AS v
  ON v.option_id = o.option_id;
```

The `IN(2,3,4,...)` predicate is where you specify multiple attributes. There's no need to add more joins to get more attributes. They're simply returned as rows rather than columns.

This means you have to write application code to fetch all the rows of this result set and map them into fields of a single object.

From comments by @Axel, is sounds like Magento provides helper functions to do this consuming of a result set and mapping it into an object.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but this would actually be much easier to implement. Thanks. For the record, I'm using Amazon RDS, and even a micro instance has little problem with a 61-table join (or even a subquery of 61 tables joined with a subquery of 61 tables) as far as I can tell. I guess it's relative, because doing similar queries through Magento or its api is ridiculously slow. Also, from what I've seen by looking through MySQL logs, Magento doesn't take your more sensible approach and actually does use a ton of complicated JOINs (as well as using its flat index tables).

Comment: The fundamental issue with this is that it only returns the IDs and not the values from the tables that need to be joined to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be quite old issue (~10 years), but still.
Magento flat indexer paginates across all attributes with 61 limit as an author mentioned above. So, they didn't manage to invent anything better than using that limit and split huge query into sub queries with a loop.
If we source code of EAV models we could probably see that all attributes are loaded by separate selects per attribute in a loop. This is another (slow) workaround here.
There is one possible workaround to decrease amount of joins at least 2 times, but it will be useful for multi-store websites, which use store view scope as well as global scope. For single store scopes that workaround won't work.

For example query

```
SELECT e.* FROM catalog_product_entity AS e
INNER JOIN catalog_product_website AS w ON w.product_id = e.entity_id AND w.website_id = 1
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS status_global_attr ON status_global_attr.attribute_id = 84 AND status_global_attr.store_id = 0 AND status_global_attr.row_id = e.row_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS status_attr ON status_attr.attribute_id = 84 AND status_attr.store_id = 1 AND status_attr.row_id = e.row_id
WHERE IFNULL(status_attr.`value`, status_global_attr.`value`) <> 1;
```

Could be converted to

```
SELECT e.* FROM catalog_product_entity AS e
INNER JOIN catalog_product_website AS w ON w.product_id = e.entity_id AND w.website_id = 1
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS status_attr ON status_attr.attribute_id = 84 AND status_attr.store_id = 1 AND status_attr.row_id = e.row_id
WHERE IFNULL(status_attr.`value`, (SELECT status_global_attr.`value` FROM catalog_product_entity_int AS status_global_attr WHERE status_global_attr.attribute_id = 84 AND status_global_attr.store_id = 0 AND status_global_attr.row_id = e.row_id)) <> 1;
```

Magento uses 1-2 JOINs by default. Then 59 remains. Store and global values require (int)59/2 = 29 pairs of LEFT JOINs. If we replace one JOIN with sub-select we could have 59 attributes joined instead of 29. That also will perform a bit faster than the first example.
The 2nd example can be also converted to something like

```
SELECT e.* FROM catalog_product_entity AS e
INNER JOIN catalog_product_website AS w ON w.product_id = e.entity_id AND w.website_id = 1
WHERE IFNULL((SELECT status_attr.`value` FROM catalog_product_entity_int AS status_attr WHERE status_attr.attribute_id = 84 AND status_attr.store_id = 1 AND status_attr.row_id = e.row_id), (SELECT status_global_attr.`value` FROM catalog_product_entity_int AS status_global_attr WHERE status_global_attr.attribute_id = 84 AND status_global_attr.store_id = 0 AND status_global_attr.row_id = e.row_id)) <> 1;
```

So, both LEFT JOINs had been converted to sub-selects.
Mentioned examples won't fit all requirements, but in case one need to deal with imports, exports or reindexing, these examples could be somehow useful. But the last example may be slower compared to 2 previous.

P.S. Starting from 2014 Magento 1 (>=1.13 EE) and Magento 2 (>= 2.0.7 if I'm not mistaken) includes staging mode, which changed a bit the structure of catalog_product_entity table. Now row_id is a primary key. entity_id is not unique anymore, but still in use. catalog_product_entity_int also uses row_id instead of entity_id.